# Redefine (or reconfirm) Node and Vertex in 3D-GIS

Tags: gis-principle

Sorry if this sounds too broad and opinion-soliciting...

I think the difference between Node and Vertex had been discussed before (for instance) [Difference between node and vertex in GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61927/difference-between-node-and-vertex-in-gis), good and detailed discussions between renowned GIS leaders are open for us (me) to learn.

And my take is (sorry again if this is too simplistic... and I can be totally wrong...) "Vertex" is for location (xy) and "Node" includes its topology.

Is it still valid, given we now have 3D-GIS more closer than before? I mean; Vertex is the XYZ locator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me a **vertex** can be a 2d or 3d coordinate. It's a mathematical point in space (2d or 3d) where lines meet. 
(Caveat: my background is Computer Science).

A "node" is an object in an object-oriented system (C++ in the case of QGIS and Qt). As such, it can have any information attached to it (as a control point in a bezier curve, x and y coordinates on the canvas, elevation etc.). It can also be part of a network (and have a degree etc.)

I'd say that a node is an abstraction of a vertex. A node might choose to ignore the z-value, in which case it is the same as a point in 2D. Or it might include it, in which case it's 3D.

I've written code to export gdal rasters to .obj files; Blender is very specific on what it means by a vertex - xyz :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Steven Kay for additional clarity, having bezier curve in the perspective really helped me to understand the distinction.  And for the pointer e.g. [Converting DEM rasters into OBJ meshes for use in Blender](http://www.stevefaeembra.com/blog/2017/11/20/converting-dem-rasters-into-obj-meshes-for-use-in-blender) for further readings, too.